# Bounty awarded incorrectly?

Tags: support, bounties

The following flag was placed on this question:

[emacs: x-popup-menu max size constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762392/emacs-x-popup-menu-max-size-constraints)

> I put a bounty on this question, and
>   this morning I accepted an answer.
>   Then I logged in a little later and
>   saw a notice that the bounty had been
>   "auto awarded". When I checked it
>   seemed half the bounty went to the
>   *wrong* answer, and the other half of the bounty evaporated. If you can,
>   please adjust the points so that the
>   full bounty is awarded to the accepted
>   answer on this Q.

Comment: What is your question? The bounty offerer was the OP, was he confused about the new (relatively) bounty system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The user forgot to separately award the bounty, and probably only motioned to accept an answer. Because bounties are no longer tied to acceptance, the bounty would end up going, in only half amount, to the answer with the highest number of votes with at least 2 score. Which it did.

These bounty mishaps generally don't get revised, by the way.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened. I accepted the answer with 1 vote, the answer with 2 votes got the bounty. Do I remember correctly that in the past when I accepted an answer for a Q on which I had placed a bounty, the bounty was awarded to the answer that I accepted?  In fact I thought this is what happened this morning and expected this to happen and had I known I needed a separate motion to award the bounty I would have done so. The answerer who helped me missed out on the bounty.  That seems unfair to him/her.

Comment: re: "These bounty mishaps generally don't get revised" - is there a way to revise this one? I am the original poster, I am the one who posted the bounty, I intended to give the bounty to the person who helped me, and in fact the other answer was not materially helpful at all, but was more a comment, though it did get 2 votes.  I'd like you to revise this one, if possible.

Comment: @Cheeso I'm aware that you had every intent to award the bounty, and I am aware that it is somewhat unfair, but that's how it is. I am not capable of revising it myself, I'm just a normal user to Stack Overflow. And, as it were, normal mods can't do it, either.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2762392/revisions):

> Bounty Started worth 150 reputation by Cheeso Feb 8 at 13:30

So, both answers [applied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for the auto award. However: only the 2nd answer had the minimum of 2 votes, so won.

Answer (score 0):

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Accepting an answer has nothing at all to do with bounty awards, and hasn't for over 6 months.

Comment: Is there a reminder or something for low-rep users who accept answers on bounty questions? Of course, this was a high-rep user, so it's moot in this case.