# Allow user with accepted answer to notify OP for sending bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties, accepted-answer, notifications

Sometimes a person answers a bounty question really quickly and the answer is even accepted.

Due to the following points listed on the [set bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) page:

- > It is your responsibility to award the bounty during the seven-day period or the 24-hour grace period that follows it. You will receive several e-mail and site notifications as the bounty period draws to a close.
- > You must wait 24 hours before awarding a bounty.

The OP forgets to give the bounty even when he/she had mentioned it. This has happened to a number of people and myself many times.

There are two questions with similar queries:

- [Feature Request: Send Automatic Email to Users Who Accept Answer Without Awarding a Bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88640/feature-request-send-automatic-email-to-users-who-accept-answer-without-awardin)
- [Add popup alert box to choose bounty award when accepting the answer on bounty question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54444/add-popup-alert-box-to-choose-bounty-award-when-accepting-the-answer-on-bounty-q/89997#89997)

---

**My proposal for the same**

Once the answer is accepted by the OP, the person who answered the question should get the priviledge to send out a notification to the OP after a day and only one notification per day should be allowed

Comment: Why can't you use comments for this?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Use of comment is possible but that sometimes seems to upfront and might come across as rude. A notification will be more like a reminder than a personal request.

Comment: The system already bothers me enough about bounty expiration, we don't need to give users more ways to annoy people.  What if the OP accepted the answer because it was the best, but didn't think it was worth the bounty award?

Comment: @psubsee2003 If it's not worth the bounty amount, the bounty amount is  anyways going to waste. Might as well give it to a person whose answer was accepted.

Comment: If placing a comment comes across as upfront and rude, how would a personal message feel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The OP forgets to give the bounty even when he/she had mentioned it.

That's true, and it's annoying for the answerers when this happens.

However, there already is a *lot* in place to remind you of awarding a bounty - an E-Mail, several unmistakable warnings in the top bar.... more and more warnings, and the 24-hour grace period, have been added over the years, and this has reached a limit of what the system can do to get people to award the bounty.

Also, you never know *why* the bounty wasn't awarded - perhaps the user didn't forget it at all, but wasn't fully satisfied with any of the answers.

If you feel strongly that your answer absolutely deserves the bounty, consider a polite comment - but be aware that ultimately, it's the asker's prerogative to do whatever they want with it (including letting it expire).

Also note that [the bounty will be automatically awarded under certain circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

Comment: I think what you're saying does make sense to me.

Comment: This is a better answer, except the *full* bounty will be awarded to an accepted answer.

Comment: @JDB You deleted your answer. Damn.

Comment: @JDB oh, really? Didn't know that. Good to know

Comment: @JDB Aha! It's okay. I hope you don't think about the Monday now. I will accept this answer. It's about time we wind up this tiny question.